# C++ Mac preprocessor flag for base sdk

Tags: c++, macos, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard, osx-mountain-lion

I have an include file which I need to include if building against the 10.7 SDK or higher, but should not be included otherwise (i.e. for 10.6 sdk). What preprocessor flag can I use in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the `Availability.h` header, the `__MAC_10_7` preprocessor token should do what you want.

```
#include <Availability.h>

#ifdef __MAC_10_7
    // Code that requires the Mac OS X 10.7 SDK or later
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html

```
#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED > 1050  // note use of 1050 instead of __MAC_10_5
#   include <security/pam_appl.h>
#else
#   include <pam/pam_appl.h>
#endif
```

This should work with older xcode too